# Which flowers are there in this white/blue/purple wedding bouquet?

Tags: identification, flowers

My fiancée is in love with the bouquet bellow, but we have no clue about the flowers species used in it. Could someone help us? Any help is really appreciated.

[image: Blue/white/purple bouquet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see:

- white [Anemone coronaria](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_coronaria) or Poppy Anemone
- blue [Muscari racemosum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscari) or Grape Hyacinth, sometimes called Bluebell or Baby's Breath (ambiguous)
- one white fringed [Tulip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip) (the blurry white flower on the right)
- blue [Centaurea cyanus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurea_cyanus), Cornflower or Bachelor's Button
- white [Syringa vulgaris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syringa_vulgaris) or Lilac (tucked inbetween, on the left)
- probably light blue [Scilla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilla) or Squill (also blurry)
- and one flower I can't identify properly.

I assume you are planning a Spring Wedding? Except for the cornflower those are all in bloom in April / May.

Comment: Excellent Stephie...Those blue flowers you couldn't get I THINK are those nice smelling early, early bulb bloomers...very common.  SHOOT.  Right on the tip of my tongue...first bulbs to come up in spring.  Sorry, I'll have to go look it up.  So silly...very common, short stems...oh!  Hyathinseesomethingorother!!  That help?  Major grins!!  Totally early spring wedding!!  Good point...

Comment: Or were you talking about the Blue Bachelor Buttons?!  Muscari, would look similar to hya..whatever!  But I thought those came on more mid summer?  Definitely Blue Bachelor Buttons.

Comment: @stormy No, the Muscari are the Grape hyacinths, I'm wondering about the single whiteish-lavender one with the green center (slightly blurry) that loogs like a daisy but isn't a daisy....

Comment: Hyacinths...that is what I tried to say, nenerneener!  Cornflower is another name for Bachelor buttons?  Okay, these common names cause more problems than they are worth using.  The light purple guy looks like Osteospermum...sp...African Daisy?  In a light lavender.  Otherwise, no idea.  Pretty bouquet, huh!

Comment: @stormy Don't think it's Osteospermum, b/c there is one daisy-like flowers florists sometimes use as a filler with *very delicate, silky* petals. I've seen it, touched it - can't remember the name. D@&*#n!

Comment: Where I live, Cornflower is used only for common chicory. I'd go with bachelor buttons as the name for the blue.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I'm not sure I'll find those flowers here in Brazil, but knowing their names helps a lot! Thank you again!

Comment: Common names make our job oh so much more difficult.  4-5 common names per plant and only ONE botanical name, well, then those change quite frequently...for some weird reason botanical names stick, common names just confuse everything in my file retrieval system!!  Tavlima, you should be able to find lots of flowers in Brazil to achieve this very yummy color scheme.  What time of year will dictate the flowers available...When are you planning your wedding?

Comment: Could the mystery flower be waxflower?

Comment: @RDSBiagi - if you mean a variety of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamelaucium_uncinatum, certainly not. I'm talking about the single, slightly lavender-tinged large flower with thin, somewhat wavy petals and the green middle. "Wax flowers" (there are a few different flowers by that name) are typically clusters of small(-ish) blossoms with thick(-ish) petals, so no match here unless you have a counter-example. This is *soooo* bugging me, it's one of these "on the tip of my tongue" cases...

Comment: Is it a Daisy pom?